# Saving Core Data Managed Object Contexts

Tags: ios, database, performance, core-data

Consider a simple scenario below where multiple changes happen every second.

I have an entity called `Ping` which has attributes for example — `lastSentTimestamp` and `lastReceivedTimestamp`.

Say, I pinged a server and I update the `lastSentTimestamp` field. I change the value of this attribute by assigning `somePingObject.lastSentTimestamp` to `[NSDate date]`; but what happens then?

- Do I simply save the managed object context?
- Do I wait for a few more changes and then batch save? (for efficiency?)
- Do I wait for the app to go to background OR look for either application exit/terminated events?

Currently, the use case of these pings suggests that they could happen every second or every half a second. I am concerned that continuous saving of the managed object context will effect the performance of the app by constantly writing to the database.

I have read the CD programming guide but I am currently confused how I handle these particular scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If saving every second or half a second does not make sense in you scenario then save when you are finished updating the object.  If you are pinging the server all the time, try saving when whatever is pinging the server is done pinging the server or gets deallocated.